# Android - Saved Activity/Fragment State Never Clears

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

I have an Android app, composed of Fragments, that I have saving state correctly. The problem is it works a bit **too** well ;-). I'll enter some input into a couple of `EditText` elements that I then save via SharedPrefs in the "onSaveInstanceState()" method, and then hit the "Task Manager" or "Switch App" button on the phone (there's two overlapping rectangles as the icon) and swipe left to close my application. If I then go to the App Drawer and re-run the application, that saved input will still be there. I am clearing the saved instance state in the "onDestroy()" method too, but apparently that is not being called when "closing" the app from that Task Manager (confirmed via logging).

Any suggestions here? Other apps I have do not exhibit this behavior. I'd like for the saved input to be cleared when a user closes the app via Task Manager as well as probably after a set amount of time. **Any ideas of what the standard practice for state handling is here?**

I tested some apps I have and noticed the default Contacts app actually saves a new contact if you start a new one and switch to another app before explicitly saving. I guess I could do this but I'd rather not.

Below is some relevant code for a particular Fragment; thank you very much in advance for any assistance.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    Log.v(Tag, "onSaveInstanceState()");

    saveInstanceState();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.v(Tag, "onResume()");

    restoreInstanceState();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Log.v(Tag, "onDestroy()");

    clearInstanceState();
}

private void saveInstanceState() {
    Log.v(Tag, "saveInstanceState()");

    // get entered data
    String name = mTxtName.getText().toString();
    String notes = mTxtNotes.getText().toString();

    // save data in Shared Prefs
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext)
            .edit()
            .putInt(KeyAmmunitionId, mAmmunitionId)
            .putString(KeyName, name)
            .putString(KeyNotes, notes)
            .putString(StringUtils.CurrentFragmentKey, Tag)
            .commit();
}

private void restoreInstanceState() {
    Log.v(Tag, "restoreInstanceState()");

    mTxtName = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frag_manage_ammunition_txtName);
    mTxtNotes = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frag_manage_ammunition_txtNotes);

    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).contains(KeyName)) {
        String ammunitionName = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).getString(KeyName, StringUtils.EMPTY_STRING);

        mTxtName.setText(ammunitionName);
    }

    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).contains(KeyNotes)) {
        String ammunitionNotes = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).getString(KeyNotes, StringUtils.EMPTY_STRING);

        mTxtNotes.setText(ammunitionNotes);
    }
}

private void clearInstanceState() {
    Log.v(Tag, "clearInstanceState()");

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext)
            .edit()
            .remove(KeyAmmunitionId)
            .remove(KeyName)
            .remove(KeyNotes)
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using SharedPrefs, I've found that an internal headless fragment that retains its state is much easier to implement/cleaner.

Inside your fragment class you have this class....

```
/**
 * "Headless" Fragment that retains state information between
 * configuration changes.
 */
public class RetainedFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * internal storage to be kept put here
     */

    // assuming the only 'view' in the parent fragment is this editText with some string value.
    String editTextValue;

    public RetainedFragment(){
        editTextValue = ""; //init values on first time in. 
    }

    /**
     * Hook method called when a new instance of Fragment is
     * created.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState
     *            object that contains saved state information.
     */
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Ensure the data survives runtime configuration changes.
        setRetainInstance(true);

    }

    // have getter/setter methods
```

Then in your outer fagment just 'create' the UI based off the values stored in the inner headless fragment.

OR...

You can use the RetainedFragmentManager that we figured out. Its a bit wonky and can be a bit confusing to figure out at first, but its a headless fragment that allows you to store java objects in hashmap-like manner, and they will persist across configuration changes, but won't exist if your app is fully closed, etc.

https://github.com/douglascraigschmidt/POSA-15/blob/master/ex/ImageDownloads/src/vandy/mooc/common/RetainedFragmentManager.java